# How to provide additional parameter in google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I have this website  where I am planning to add google analytics features to track some parameters from user for ex `gender, pin point location, age`.

I am new to this, I just wanted to know or get some direction on how can we add additional parameters to Google analytics or you can say how to inject this requirement with Google analytics. I just need some heads up.

Thanks for your time guys !

Comment: Not sure what you are asking for. Please specify and give examples and show what you have investigated. What do you mean by 'ex gender' and ' pin point location'?

Answer (score 3):

Analytics has already in place a somewhat limited [demographic report](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2799357?hl=en), but it is not clear whether you want to provide this information by yourself, or check what Google can track for you.

You should also take a look to [Custom Dimensions](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets) in Google Analytics. Those allow you to add any kind of data to your tracking, assuming you already figured how to get it from your users.

Just be aware, there is a limit to custom dimensions in free accounts, and you should never log personal information, according to the ToS.

Answer (score 2):

It's actually pretty easy to send custom information. Basic form, assuming yoh have a `ga` object is:

```
ga('send', 'event', category, action, label, count);
```

This allows you to track hierarchical data in GA, where you have broad categories, and specific "events" or actions that are interesting. If you have additional information about those events, you can add a label or a count.

So you might want to track a "login" or "create user" event and, there you might track that info you want with a label.